# NixOS: Setting the default channel in configuration.nix

Tags: nix, nixos

How do I set the default channel in NixOS's `/etc/configuration.nix`?

There is a command to set it and rebuild with

```
sudo nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
sudo nixos-rebuild switch -I nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixpkgs
```

but I'd like to have it setup in configuration.nix so I don't have to remember how to do this everytime. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`system.autoUpgrade.channel` is what you might be looking for

set it to any channel e.g.

`system.autoUpgrade.channel = "https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-16.03-small/";`

the documentation says:

> by default, this is the channel set using **nix-channel** (run
>   `nix-channel --list` to see the current value)

an up to date list of channels can be found on https://nixos.org/channels/

ref: https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-system.autoUpgrade.channel
https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#idm140737317454064

Comment: Thanks this looks promising. Unfortunately my experimentation with NixOS has ended so I can't verify this. If anyone can verify then I'll select this as the answer.

Comment: Say you had the system on 19.03 initially, and then you set this autoupgrade channel to 19.09. It goes thru with auto upgrade and all is well... But then you run `nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade` and... you rollback to the previous version, right? That doesn't feel good...

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation doesn't specify this, but it looks like if you have more than one channel it uses the first one alphabetically as your default. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 6):

Set `nixPath = [ "nixpkgs=http://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable/nixexprs.tar.xz" ];`, see https://github.com/snabblab/snabblab-nixos/blob/d8b9761b107293891b19021f2f0f77a0e3ba3746/modules/common.nix#L39

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work similarly as using `nix-channel`, if I understood correctly what was going on. First, when running `nixos-rebuild switch`, it upgraded nixpkgs by downloading the tar.xz file. Second, almost(?) every time nixpkgs was needed, it was downloaded. How can I have functionality as when setting with `nix-channel`? That is, upgrading nixpkgs only when explicitly asked. Still, the channel could be set in configuration.nix. Does this make sense?

Comment: @JaakkoLuttinen you could use `nixpkgs="${fetchTarball http://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable/nixexprs.tar.xz}"`, this way, the fetching would only happen at nixos-rebuild time, and at runtime the system would see an already spliced-in nix store path

Answer (score 3):

The `nix.nixPath` ([ref](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#nixpath)) option looks like it will do what you're after.

Also the nixos-unstable channel might be more appropriate for you, rather than nixpkgs-unstable. I believe the pkgs in the nixpkgs channel are tested and built for non-nixOS systems, though I can't remember a reference for that at the moment.

```
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable/ 
nix-channel --update nixos-unstable
```

```
# /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
# Put nixos-unstable at the front of nixPath
{ lib, ... }:
{
  nix.nixPath = lib.mkDefault (lib.mkBefore [ "nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos-unstable" ]);
}
```

<strike>If you want the imperative nix-channel commands in your configuration.nix as well you could write a small systemd service to do so, as shown [here](https://nixos.org/wiki/NixOS:extend_NixOS#Using_systemd).</strike>
Edit: To ensure `configuration.nix` is built from the latest `unstable` channel just set the value of `nixpkgs` as in the answer from @iElectric and Nix will use the expressions contained at that URL whenever it evaluates `configuration.nix`.

PS I realised you could also just point the nixos path to the nixos-unstable channel by doing `nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable/ nixos` but I think the first solution is clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It looks like that can replace the `nixos-rebuild` command, however how can I add the unstable channel itself in `configuration.nix`?

Comment: Warning: this does not work out-of-the-box (anymore at least): the path is wrong, and it removes required entries like nixos-config...

Comment: @olejorgenb, the `nixPath` value might need to be wrapped in a `lib.mkDefault` to avoid replacing the `nixos-config` value. I don't have a NixOS setup currently to check that though. But the NixOS manual still has the `nixPath` option so I think it's still the appropriate option to use. I think that path should still work as well, though it seems I accidentally omitted the initial `/`, I will amend that.