# How to install a nix channel in a NixOS VM?

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I'm using [microvm](https://github.com/astro/microvm.nix/) to create and run a NixOS vm (on a Debian system with the [nix](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/nix) packet manager installed).

The NIX_PATH environment variable inside the VM is set to its [default value](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=unstable&show=nix.nixPath&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=nix%20path):

```
nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
```

The nixpkgs path referenced above however does not exist on the VM, `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/` is empty.

How can I configure the VM so that it gets built with a working reference to the nixpkgs channel that was also used to build the VM?

These questions seem to be similar, but I'm not sure yet:

- [how to add NixOS unstable channel declaratively in configuration.nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831392/how-to-add-nixos-unstable-channel-declaratively-in-configuration-nix)
- [NixOS: Setting the default channel in configuration.nix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452057/nixos-setting-the-default-channel-in-configuration-nix)

My flake.nix to build the microvm:

```
{
  description = "NixOS in MicroVMs";

  inputs.microvm.url = "github:astro/microvm.nix";
  inputs.microvm.inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, microvm }:
    let
      system = "x86_64-linux";
      user = "REDACTED";
      vmname = "haskell";
    in {
      defaultPackage.${system} = self.packages.${system}.my-microvm;

      packages.${system} = {
        my-microvm = self.nixosConfigurations.my-microvm.config.microvm.declaredRunner;
      };

      nixosConfigurations = {
        my-microvm = nixpkgs.lib.nixosSystem {
          inherit system;
          modules = [
            microvm.nixosModules.microvm
            ({pkgs, ... }: {
              environment.systemPackages = [
                pkgs.ghc
                pkgs.git
                (pkgs.haskell-language-server.override { supportedGhcVersions = [ "94" ]; })
                pkgs.stack
              ];
              microvm = {
                forwardPorts = [
                  { from = "host"; host.port = 2222; guest.port = 22; }
                ];
                hypervisor = "qemu";
                interfaces = [
                  { type = "user"; id = "usernet"; mac = "00:00:00:00:00:02"; }
                ];
                mem = 4096;
                shares = [ {
                  proto = "9p";
                  tag = "ro-store";
                  source = "/nix/store";
                  mountPoint = "/nix/.ro-store";
                } {
                  proto = "virtiofs";
                  tag = "hometest";
                  source = "~/.local/share/microvm/vms/${vmname}/shares/home";
                  mountPoint = "/home/${user}";
                  socket = "/run/user/1000/microvm-virtiofsd_vm_home";
                }
                ];
                socket = "/run/user/1000/microvm-control.socket";
                vcpu = 3;
                volumes = [];
                writableStoreOverlay = "/home/${user}/nix-rw-store";
              };
              networking.hostName = vmname;
              nix.settings = {
                extra-experimental-features = ["nix-command" "flakes"];
                trusted-users = [user];
              };
              security.sudo = {
                enable = true;
                wheelNeedsPassword = false;
              };
              services.getty.autologinUser = user;
              services.openssh = {
                enable = true;
              };
              users.users.${user} = {
                extraGroups = [ "wheel" "video" ];
                group = "user";
                isNormalUser = true;
                openssh.authorizedKeys.keys = [
                  "ssh-rsa REDACTED"
                ];
                password = "";
              };
              users.users.root.password = "";
              users.groups.user = {};
            })
          ];
        };
      };
    };
}
```

Comment: You don't need channels with the modern flake-based approach you're using. Just specify `inputs.nixpkgs.url` to pin a specific version.

Comment: I use the VM as a Haskell dev environment. When I run `stack setup` in a Haskell project I see:
  error: file 'nixpkgs' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I)

I added
inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
as line 6 in my flake but it did not change anything.

Comment: Ah, so you're running software inside the image that expects a traditional channel. There's a setting you can point at the nixpkgs you get from the flake inputs to work around that, but I don't remember it off the top of my head and don't have time to look it up to build an answer right now. If you don't get any responses here in a reasonable amount of time, maybe bring it to the NixOS Discourse forum?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, what I actually needed was to have `<nixpkgs>` resolve inside the VM. This I achieved by setting this option in the VM config:

```
nix.nixPath = ["nixpkgs=${builtins.storePath <nixpkgs>}"];
```

And running the flake with `nix run --impure`. Impure is necessary because builtins.storePath is input from outside.

I discussed this issue also here: https://github.com/astro/microvm.nix/issues/175

Comment: I'd think it'd be a lot cleaner to work with a more static/pure reference where you'd pin your nixpkgs to a specific commit which might also allow you to avoid using `nix run --impure`.